# First Order Stochastic Dominance given a functional form

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Assume I have a particular function $u(x)= \sqrt x $ (note: $u'(x)\geq0,  u'(x) \leq 0, \forall x$)

Assume that I have ***two*** continuous, probability distributions over $x$, $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ but that they are unknown (we know they exist but we dont know what they look like)

Assume the following about the expectations given the two distributions: $\int u(x)dF(x) \geq \int u(x)dG(x)$

**(1)**

Given the information above, based on **one specific functional form** of $u(x)$, can I conclude: $F(x)\leq G(x), \forall x$?

**(2)**

If I assume $u(x)$ such that $\quad u'(x)\geq0, \quad u'(x) \leq 0 \quad \forall x$
(but **do not specify** what functional form $u(x)$ takes)

and I know $\int u(x)dF(x) \geq \int u(x)dG(x)$

can I conclude: $F(x)\leq G(x), \forall x$ ?

Answer (score 2):

For **(1)**, the answer is clearly no. For example, let $F(x)$ be the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ and $G(x)$ be the cdf of the degenerate distribution
$$\mathbf P(X=1/2)=1.$$
Then it is easy to see that 
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}0, &\text{if }x<0\\x,&\text{if }0\le x<1\\1,&\text{if } x\ge 1\end{cases},\,\,\,G(x)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }x<1/2\\1,&\text{if }x\ge 1/2\end{cases}.$$
Clearly, (Note that although $G$ is not continuous here, it can be arbitrarily approximated by a distribution function that is continuous)
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x)\,dF(x)=\frac 23< \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x)\,dG(x)=\sqrt{\frac 12}.$$
But clearly, neither "$F(x)\ge G(x)$ for all $x$" nor "$G(x)\ge F(x)$ for all $x$" holds.

For **(2)**, if you mean "for SOME $u(x)$ satisfying $u'\ge 0$ and $u''\le 0$, the inequality holds", then the answer is clearly the same as **(1)**, since $u(x)$ could rightly be the function you specified in **(1)**. But if you mean "for ALL $u(x)$ satisfying $u'\ge 0$ and $u''\le 0$, the inequality holds", then the answer is yes, because $F$ first-order stochastically dominates $G$ if and only if 
$$\int u(x)\,dF(x)\ge\int u(x)\,dG(x)$$
for EACH concave and increasing function $u(x)$, while each concave and increasing function can be approximated by a function which is twice differentiable, increasing, and concave.

Comment: Hi Onol,  Thank you for responding. Well then I am not sure what to say any more. If I know $F(x)\leq G(x), \forall x$ I can always conclude $\int u(x)dF(x) \geq \int u(x)dG(x)$, for all nondecreasing $u$, I dont need to check what possible functions satify it as long as I know they are nondecreasing. but based on what your saying and what I suspected I cannot say if $\int u(x)dF(x) \geq \int u(x)dG(x)$ then $F(x)\leq G(x), \forall x$ unless I check every possible $u$ in the universe. Just because I have $\int u(x)dF(x) \geq \int u(x)dG(x)$ for 1 specific function $u(x)$ I cannot assume FOSD.

Comment: For case **(1)** mentioned above. Could I at least conclude SOSD? Adding the assumption that $u$ is concave. For **some** that is under consideration? ie I dont have to check for all $u$'s.

Comment: @jessica For your first comment, yes, you cannot conclude $F(x)\le G(x)$ for all $x$ just based on testing the integral inequality for SOME function $u$. You know, that property is often useful in the converse way: if you know that $F$ FOSD $G$ then for any function nondecreasing you can obtain the integral inequality.

Comment: @jessica For your second comment, unfortunately, the answer is still no. To illustrate, let us shift the degenerate distribution a little bit to $\mathbf P(X=1/2-\epsilon)=1$ for some sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$. Then you can still get the integral inequality for $u(x)=\sqrt x$, but it is easy to see that $\int_0^1 xdF(x)=1/2>\int_0^1xdG(x)=1/2-\epsilon$, which means that $G$ fails to second order stochastically dominate $F$.

Comment: Onol, I really appreciate your help. The reason I am asking these questions is because lets say you have a "big U" $U(L)$ expected utility function that is VNM, with a concave bernuli utility, and it satisfies all the necessary axioms of EUH. Since $U(L)$ is a utility representing preferences of lotteries, we can say: $U(L_1)>U(L_2)$ IFF agent prefers lottery $L_1$ to $L_2$. From what I gather from our discussion is even if an agent, with a VNM function that satifies EUH, and has concave bernulli utility, a preference lottery $L_1$ to $L_2$ does not imply *either* $L_1$ FOSD or SOSD $L_2$

Comment: I am just wondering how 1 lottery being prefered to another fits with FOSD/SOSD condition. I would have guessed, if you have a concave berunlu utility, at minimumum, if you prefer one lottery over the other, you should **at least** get SOSD.